# When setting the context do you link the file name or database name?

Tags: java, tomcat, wampserver

Say I have a file call testDataBase.sql but if I was open it in WAMP id have to do "use test" which of these do I use when setting up the Web.xml and context.xml?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, but if the question is which name to use when the database's filename differs from the database name, there is a way to find out. Experiment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the name of the database you find in the sql file, not the file name itself.